# Disqus throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, disqus

I am trying to use disqus. The steps I have followed are

```
gem install disqus
```

config block in `application.rb`

```
config.after_initialize do
    Disqus::defaults[:account] = "youraccountname"
    # so that the comments will load up in development environment
    Disqus::defaults[:developer] = true
    Disqus::defaults[:container_id] = "disqus_thread"
    Disqus::defaults[:show_powered_by] = false
    end
```

In the view

```
> <%= post.body %><% end %> <%= disqus_thread %>  </div>  <script
> type="text/javascript"
> src="http://disqus.com/forums/rapexegesis/embed.js"></script>
```

I get the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `disqus_thread' for #<#<Class:0x2e5a560>:0x2e5dc50>
Extracted source (around line #13):



11:                 <p>                             
12:                 <%= post.body %><% end %>
13: <div id ="disqus_thread">
14: <%= disqus_thread %>
15: </div>
16: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/rapexegesis/embed.js"></script>
```

I am missing anything here?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind Passenger, apache or whatever server, try to restart it.